# PayPal.ConnectionException: Invalid HTTP response: The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel

Tags: ssl, paypal

I am getting a problem with the PayPal REST Api, sometimes it works fine! (and on sandbox it works 100%) But on the live system when connecting to the live PayPal system. I sometimes get the follow error.

```
PayPal.ConnectionException: Invalid HTTP response: The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel. at 
PayPal.Api.HttpConnection.Execute(String payLoad, HttpWebRequest 
    httpRequest) at PayPal.Api.PayPalResource.ConfigureAndExecute[T]
    (APIContext apiContext, HttpMethod httpMethod, String resource, String 
    payload, String endpoint, Boolean setAuthorizationHeader) at 
    PayPal.Api.OAuthTokenCredential.GenerateOAuthToken() at 
    PayPal.Api.OAuthTokenCredential.GetAccessToken()
```

Basically is just keep crashing when trying to get the access token from PayPal

I have updated the SDK to the latest version and the code had been happily working for +3 months.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It looks like in some cases the PayPal connection is not released for some reason. this creates an error as there is a limit in .Net to the number of concurrent web connections to any single host, that limit is 2.

Add this before you try and connect to PayPal, remember it needs to go before every connection e.g if you are using the SDK and the express checkout.

```
ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = true;
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit = 9999;

//PayPay SDK connection
var apiContext = Configuration.GetAPIContext();
```

Comment: I had the same problem and this solution worked for me.

Comment: Thank you. Mine was consistently failing for the last few weeks. This worked.

Comment: I have the same issue, but have Configuration.GetAcctAndConfig() and returns Dictionary<string, string> variable. Have follow the merchant api code from github. Can you please guide where to put the above settings in this code.
thanks in advance

Comment: @TheAlbear your code working but i am getting another error previous error in cleared

Answer (score 9):

This error is occurring because PayPal have started to drop support for SSLv3. Regarding the accepted answer, only the `Tls12` setting is required to get the PayPal connection working again.

I didn't want to have to implement this setting all over my code. I found that putting this setting in the `Application_Start()` method of my `global.asax` file was the best solution.

**Also, my version 4.0 NET framework didn't allow me to use the `SecurityProtocolType.Tls12` flag** - but it works if I cast it like this:

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = (SecurityProtocolType)3072; // This is equivalent to SecurityProtocolType.Tls12
}
```

Comment: @Jamesmaccormack i am getting the new error after adding this

Comment: @MeerDeen You should really open a new SO question as your problem is not related to my answer. However I have looked it up and believe you are being restricted from making calls from your IP address (geolocation restriction). See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35663028/i-cant-configure-paypal-to-use-in-asp-net-mvc-application

Answer (score 2):

I have similar issue with Paypal Test Account and for fix it enough only one row from previous answer:

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
```

Answer (score 1):

In my first answer I recommended add

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol =  SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
```

But My Project using Amazon service also, and it not working with TLS12. It's work fine when I replace it on pack of protocols:

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
```