# I can't configure Paypal to use in ASP.NET MVC application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, paypal-sandbox, paypal

I want to integrate PayPal to my application.
I have read a lot of articles, including official documentation. I.e.
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/870870/Using-Paypal-Rest-API-with-ASP-NET-MVC
https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-NET-SDK
and do step by step. No result :(

First at all, I installed package PayPal from Nuget:

> Install-Package Paypal

Secondly, I went to my paypal account and created test application:

[image]

My web.config:

[image]

when I call

```
        var config = ConfigManager.Instance.GetProperties();

        // Use OAuthTokenCredential to request an access token from PayPal
        var accessToken = new OAuthTokenCredential(config).GetAccessToken();
```

it throws exception:

> Retried 1 times.... Exception in PayPal.HttpConnection.Execute().
>   Check log for more details.

(which log should I check - don't understand...)

when I check by debugger I see, that object **config** has configurations clientId and clientSecret correctly

[image]

what is wrong (or maybe I lost something)?

Also, documentation has link https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/ , but I can't open this link at all. Maybe, I should allow something more?

Comment: What do you get when you try to open the sandbox.paypal.com URL?  It's loading fine for me and I use it heavily every day.  If you can't connect to that, then whatever is causing that is probably also causing your API request failures.

Comment: page is not opened at all. "This webpage is not available. ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT"

Comment: @AndrewAngell, thank you, really. I just tried from PC with US address and it works. And it does not work for my Ukrainian address

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does not work because my IP address in not allowed for it (restriction by country). More detail information about it https://developer.paypal.com/docs/faq/#international-developer-questions

Thank you, Andrew Angell

Comment: so what is the solution then?

Comment: @kritikaTalwar, use proxy

Answer (score 0):

It's network proxy that blocking Paypal API request